# C# comboBox, readall and working directory

Tags: c#

What I have is a comboBox being populated from a code:

```
InitializeComponent();
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"K:\ases");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.ssi", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
```

Then i'm trying to ReadAllText from that selected item.

```
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(comboBox1.Text);
```

When executed, it tries to read the file from the locale path, and of course the file isnt there.  I also can't set the working directory because the comoboBox is populated from a huge range of subdirectories.  How do I get the working directory of the item selected in the combobox WITHOUT expossing the whole directory path to the user?

Any help always welcomed

I thought i saw a few answers with someone suggesting private and hiding things in a combox box, where those suggestions taken down.  is there a way to keep the full file info in the combobox and only display the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to accomplish this, but the absolute easiest would be to store the directory path in an instance variable (we'll call it `directoryPath`) and use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to reconstruct the path:

(some code eliminated for brevity)

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private string directoryPath;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"K:\ases");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.ssi", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }

        directoryPath = dinfo.FullName;
    }

    private void YourFunction()
    {
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, comboBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

You could also try adding the `FileInfo` to the `ComboBox` rather than the file's name and use `SelectedItem` rather than `Text`:

```
    InitializeComponent();

    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"K:\ases");
    comboBox1.DataSource = dinfo.GetFiles("*.ssi", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Then you can do this to retrieve the file:

```
FileInfo file = (FileInfo)comboBox1.SelectedItem;

string contents = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that both of my codes are under thier own seperate private void

Comment: @Mike: That was my assumption. Either of these approaches should work just fine with that.

Comment: This is sooo close, except for the file exists under the SearchOption.AllDirectories, not under dinfo.  I know directoryPath = dinfo.FullName is the problem but how do i resolve it to the full path of the found file?

Comment: directoryPath = file.FullName; in the foreach pulls all the paths :/

Comment: @Mike: If the files are coming from subdirectories, then the second solution (using the `DataSource` property and setting the `DisplayMember`) is definitely the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
```

do:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(file.FullName);
```

This will get you the full path to the file in order to read it.

See [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_members.aspx) for more details and other properties to use.

Comment: He specifically stated that he didn't want to expose the whole path to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for you is to use special class for items:

```
class FileInfoItem {
    public FileInfoItem(FileInfo info) {
        Info = info;
    }

    public FileInfo Info { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Info.Name;
    }
}
```

To add items in the combo box use the following code:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new FileInfoItem(file));
```

ComboBox will display the ToString() value of the items and also you can get the original FileInfo in the following maner:

```
((FileInfoItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Info;
```

Comment: Why wrap the `FileInfo` class when you can just change the `DisplayMember` attribute of the ComboBox to display the file name?