# c# application to select a file by default on a button click

Tags: c#, sql

I have an application designed for executing some sql script file. After connecting to the server, the user retrieves the database list which is populated in a drop down box.

What I want to achieve is that when I select a database and when clicking on execute button it should select a file (by default which we define) and execute.

How can I set some default file to get selected?

Comment: well, one good way would be simply remembering ( e.g. saving to settings/file and restoring upon program start ) the last opened file and simply use it as default until the user selects a different one

Comment: What do you mean by "select a database say master and when clicking on execute button it should select a file(by default which we define) and execute", what you want to execute?

Comment: @Popeye: Actually the file here I specified is an sql file(filename.sql). So, what I do here is that when user selects one database (for example master db) my application should automatically check for a file in a location (for example in the installation folder) and execute that file.

Comment: Have a 2nd dropdown box with a list of files to be executed where the default file was/is the last used one which you can save on the list at the top? Save the file on the project settings? Have a file to store the default file? I don't know your requirements is pretty vague to me and there are plenty of solutions to it.

Comment: @Prix: But how can I give since database may get changed for different users?

Comment: @VysakhVenugopal then have a list of files per user?

Comment: @Prix: Is it possible to give a default path for those filenames?If I choose to go with drop down box for files?

Comment: You can use a default folder and then use a Directory function to get all the files that ends with .sql to load on the list for the user to select one for example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35402/discussion-between-vysakh-venugopal-and-prix)

Comment: For example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119323/342740 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/1947422/342740 and sorry not joining the chat.

Comment: Thanks for that.. I will check and will let you know

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Najzero, but to further expand it, let me start by saying you should explain why you need a default file and why not using a hard coded "c:\default.txt"?

now that we said that, if that default file is not hard coded, then you should use the project Resources

[image]

and add a string there for your default value.

to read on resources go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader(v=vs.90).aspx)

and to use the resources do

```
Properties.Resources.defaultVal
```